# Edit an element in a nested List

Tags: c#, list, nested-lists

I have a nested list elements. I need to change a particular element in that list.

```
public List<List<string>> index = new List<List<string>>();
```

From that list I need to change the value. searching a specific word in it, if it has, i need get the index, then change the value.

Comment: So, what is the question? `index[3][2] = ...` is the correct answer.

Comment: I want to search a element it has, then change the value to another value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iterate over the main list, then search the index of the word you wanna change, if find it, change it and stop the iteration.

```
List<List<string>> index = new List<List<string>>();
foreach (List<string> list in index)
{
    int i = list.IndexOf("word to search");
    if (i >= 0) {
        list[i] = "new word";
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you plan to use Linq you can use a [selector that also gets the index of the source element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
    static bool SearchAndReplace (List<string> strings, string valueToSearch, string newValue)
    {
        var found = strings.Select ((s,i)=> new{index=i, val=s}).FirstOrDefault(x=>x.val==valueToSearch);
        if (found != null)
        {
            strings [found.index] = newValue;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    static bool SearchAndReplace (List<List<string>> stringsList, string valueToSearch, string newValue)
    {
        foreach (var strings in stringsList)
        {
            if (SearchAndReplace(strings, valueToSearch, newValue))
                return true;
        }
        return false;

    }
```